# C++ conditional function calling with type traits

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

Suppose I have a class template `template <typename T> class X`

Is it somehow possible to use type traits or a similar technique to call a (static) method of T but only if the type T declares such method, e.g. something like this:

```
template <typename T> 
class X {
    static void foo(){
       if(has_method(T,bar)) //Something like this      
         T::bar(); //If T has no bar() method, then foo does nothing
    }

};
```

Comment: Search for "tag dispatching" and take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/257288/500104).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template <typename T>
class X {
public:
    static void foo() {
        foo_impl(static_cast<T*>(nullptr));
    }
private:
    // foo_impl #1
    template <typename U>
    static auto foo_impl(U*) -> decltype(U::bar(), void()) {
        U::bar();
    }

    // foo_impl #2
    static void foo_impl(...) {}
};
```

Because of the SFINAE rule, `foo_impl` #1 is not in the overload set when `U::bar()` is not a valid expression, and `foo_impl` #2 gets called instead.  If type deduction does succeed for `foo_impl` #1, it will always be a better conversion than the ellipsis.

Ideone demo: http://ideone.com/UKVmIB

Answer (score 2):

First, you'll want to make the decision at compile time, since
otherwise, you'll need to provide the function, even if you
never go into the branch.  I can imagine something like:

```
template <typename T, void (T::*)() > struct HasBar;

template <typename T>
void doBar( HasBar<&T::bar>* ) { T::bar(); }

template <typename T>
void doBar( ... ) {}

template <typename T>
class X
{
    static void f()
    {
        doBar<T>( 0 );
    }
};
```

It's a more or less classic trick; if `&T::bar` fails (because
T doesn't have a member bar), then the instantiation of `doBar(
HasBar<...>)` fails, the function is not added to the overload
set, so the other one is called.  If `&T::bar` is a legal
expression, both function templates can be successfully
instantiated, and the conversion of `0` to a pointer is chosen
before a match with `...` (which is always the last resort when
determining function overload resolution).

EDIT:

I missed the fact that the function was static.  The above is
for a non-static function.  For a static function, change the
first line to:

```
template <typename T, void (*)() struct HasBar;
```

The rest should work as is.

Comment: What is `void (&T::bar)()`?

Comment: @aschepler An error:-).  When you take the address, it should be just `&T::bar`.  I'll correct it.

Comment: Using function pointers disqualifies functions like `static void bar(int n=0);`.  (But I don't think there's any solution for that using only C++03.)

Comment: @aschepler Good point.  But in the classes you're instantiating it over, you can always overload: just add `static void bar() { bar(0); }` and drop the default argument.